# Is it possible to select and insert its result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, select, insert

I have a table that needs to be updated with another table. Can I make a Select command to insert the data found on another table? If so, how?

I use MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
insert into table1
(Column1, Column2)
select Column1, Column2
from table2
```